# Socket.io with nodeJs and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm creating a Chat App with Socket.io, React, and NodeJS.

Here is my NodeJs Server (In this folder: https://myurl.com/websocket/chat) :

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const http = require("https");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const { Server } = require("socket.io");
    app.use(cors());
    
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    
    // Socket IO
    const io = new Server(server, {
        path: '/websocket/chat/socket.io',
        cors: {
            origin: "*",
          },
    });
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => { ....})
    server.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log('Server Run')
})
```

And Here is my React Socket.Io Client Code :

```
const socket = io.connect("https://myurl.com/websocket/chat" , { path: '/websocket/chat/socket.io'});
```

I tried many things but it does not work and can't find a way to make it work. I fixed all Cors errors, but I still have this one :

```
https://myurl.com/websocket/chat/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OSJKnZO 500
```

Comment: Try with the right port `3002` on your client : https://myurl.com:3002/websocket/chat and tell me

Comment: Thanks for Help, Tried but it does not work. I send a message to my Hosting Service and they do not allow WebSocket on they server. This is why it does not work,